# Gerrit missing all-projects

Tags: ubuntu, gerrit

I accidently deleted allprojects.git file on the server and now when I am trying to go to Projects via Web UI I get Missing All-Projects error, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All-Projects is very critical.  It holds information on permissions and group membership.  If you don't have a backup copy somewhere, your best bet is to re-install gerrit and import your existing projects.